# How do I get Facebook accessToken after login?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I can login but I need to get the `accessToken`, so that other APIs like *get friends* etc. can be invoked.

The method, `getLoginStatus`, gets called but doesn't get into the `success` block on response.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: <<My appId>>, // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth: true
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            alert('response='+response);
        });
        window.setTimeout(checkLogStatus, 1000);
        function checkLogStatus(){
            alert("check");
            // fetch the status on load
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                alert('response='+response);
            });
        }
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the accessToken

The SDK is usually able to handle the access token on its own pretty well – including it in any following requests to the API automatically, without any need for you to do something manually.

So it’s not really clear to me, what problem you are actually having/trying to solve here.